# fabric.js 2.4 Imported SVG, how to get the actual paths relative to canvas?

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

User has imported an SVG file into Canvas and made some transformations. Rotation, move, scale, etc.
How can I get the actual paths making up the object, relative to canvas and accounting for transformations?

Comment: How are you loading the svg into your canvas?

Comment: Using fabric.js.. either way.. what I want is to convert for example "M 953 378 l -114 328 l 117 21 q 165 -451 165 -518" to an array of points

Comment: FabricJS isn't really the best library for performing path manipulation since it works more on the basis of applying transformations to the original path data. PaperJS would probably be better suited for what you're trying to do - http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/

Comment: maybe I phrased my question wrong. Would you recommend any javascript library to convert an SVG path string into an array of vertices?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert your paths to polygons? Keep in mind that paths support curves and arcs which you won't be able to reproduce exactly with an array of points.

Comment: @melchiar that's exactly what I need. Curves and arcs should be 'rasterized' or approximated to a set resolution. Which way should I go? Thanks

Comment: In that case you should probably edit your question to explain what you're trying to do more specifically. Here's a good guide to read on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask